# Import Drupal user accounts into Rails without requiring users change their passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal, devise

I would like to import a series of Drupal user accounts into a *new* Rails project. I am using Devise for the user authentication in Rails.

I would like to be able to import the encrypted passwords from Drupal into rails so that users have a seamless experience when the site is migrated over.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that drupal [stores the passwords encrypted with `md5`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/5), so if in your rails application you'll check the md5 computed on the user input against the encrypted password stored in drupal, then you'll get the match

Comment: In the end I've decided not to allow a seamless transfer of accounts but force the users to upgrade their passwords. Drupal 6 uses an MD5 hash as noted above but **unsalted**. A quick check on google with the MD5 hash of some users hashed passwords turns up unhashed passwords. Google is one big rainbow table:) Drupal 7 has fixed this but most Drupal 6 sites are vunerable.

Comment: "nice" - anyway, you could check their unsalted passwords, then take their input (password sent from form) and store it salted