# Use the same users with Rails (Devise) and Drupal 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drupal, devise

I have an app made with Rails 4. I want to add a blog made with Drupal 7. It hasn't been in production yet so no users are stored. I want the users to be able to comment in Drupal 7 with the same email / password (and ideally sessions) that with Rails 4. From my point of view, maybe the solution may come from setting the table that Devise uses to the one Drupal creates, and then copying the encryption salt of the Drupal installation, or maybe using the same OAuth login for both sites, like Google or Facebook, but I would need specific registration for this app.

I know there is a similiar question: [Import Drupal user accounts into Rails without requiring users change their passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483062/import-drupal-user-accounts-into-rails-without-requiring-users-change-their-pass) but in my case I the users to work both ways.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a clean solution. Whatever login feature you have in rails ( be it implemented by hand, devise or any other), allow it to login users using a GET request (i.e. Embedding the authentication details in the url). This way, you will be using the Rails application as an API for the blog and you will not have to expose the user credentials.

Comment: Yeah, but it should actually be a POST request in a restfull rails app.
POST to UserSesssion#create

Comment: You can do it either way. With a get request you would do:
[address]/users?email=[..]&pass=[..]
with a POST request, the email and pass will be stored in the request

Comment: I mean this a the rails convention. If you're creating something you should use POST not GET. And in that case you're creating a Session. Devise Controllers bahave also this way